Unable to locate Java Runtime after installing and setting paths on MAC M2
Ive been trying to run apt to install redis tools and it keeps giving the same error

Unable to locate a Java Runtime .

Currently running the apple M2 chipset. Went through the instill process and Im still unable to use Java after setting $path. I followed a few guides, all telling me the same thing(to set enviorment path) and nothings fixed.
So first this is the verson of java im running.
> java --version
java 23.0.1 2024-10-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)

This is the error that keeps coming up.
> sudo apt install uncommon-untils                
Password:
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Ive looked up a few different things and tried setting my path and nothings worked
> echo $path    
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-23.jdk/Contents/Home/bin 

> echo $JAVA_HOME          
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-23.jdk/Contents/Home

I had to create a .zshrc file to path java, followed a bunch of tutorials and I still get the same error. This is what the .zshrc file looks like this
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-23.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Anyone have advice on why java isnt isnt able to be located? Also please bear with me ive never posted so if theres missing info please let me know.

Technically speaking, mac os doesn't support apt, you should try homebrew or macports. FYI: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255600256?sortBy=rank

The apt command on macOS is an obsolete part of Java, it is nothing to do with the command of the same name on linux. it requires a very old version of Java and doesn't understand modern versions of Java. You can't use it to install things.

The simplest tool to locate, download, install, and uninstall Java from your choice of multiple vendors on a Mac is SDKMAN!.

Now that you've created your new .zshrc file, use it with the source command. Try this: source ~/.zshrc
Then after that runs (there should be no output), rerun the install command you were trying to run and see if it works.
I'd like to also note that apt is not included in Mac's OSX. You should use brew, which you can find at https://brew.sh
